# Get data on jquery after ajax has loaded the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I wanted to load all images from a directory using ajax call and accept one after it is added to html. I have successfully load all images. But My problem is that i can't access its attribute in jQuery after it is inserted in html.

How can I access an image attribute after it is been added by jQuery ajax call.

My jQuery code for accessing image src is

```
     $("button").click(function(){
       $("#div1").load("demo.php");
     });
      $("#div1 img").click(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr("src"));
      });
```

my html is :

```
       <div id="div1"></div>
       <button>Click Here</button>
```

and my demo.php is

```
        <?php
       $directory = /path/to/folder/;
       $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
       foreach($images as $image)
       {
     echo "<img class='imgr' src='$image'/>";
     }
      ?>
```

I am able to load images to the div1 element but I can't access its attributes. I have changed the '**#div1 img**' to '**img**' and '**.imgr**' but with no luck.

Comment: Try this: `$('#div1').on('click', 'img', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr("src"));
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the data is loaded dynamically.

Change;

```
 $("#div1 img").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

to

```
$( "#div1" ).on( "click", "img", function() {
   console.log($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind click event on elements that doesn't exist when the script is loaded.
You can change this:

```
$("#div1 img").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

to this:

```
$('#div1').on('click', "img", function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have click event on parent div in order to delegate click events to children that are not part of the DOM yet, please check this [link](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on event delegation

Try this instead:

```
  $("#div1").on('click', 'img', function(){
     console.log($(this).attr("src"));
  });
```

Comment: `img` should be wrapped in `'` quotes!

Comment: and remove the dot after `.on`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `$(document).on("click" , "" , function() {});`

```
$(document).on("click", "#div1 img", function() {
     console.log($(this).attr("src"));
});
```